# Semantic UI how to place right items in a menu

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I want to place the Login, Sign Up and search bar items to the right of the menu, but they all kind of get "squashed" together. How can I place multiple items to the right then?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui menu">
        <a class="item" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="item" href="#">About</a>
        <a class="item" href="#">Contact us</a>
        <div class="right item" href="#">
            <div class="ui icon input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                <i class="search icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="ui primary button">Sign Up</div>
            <div class="ui button">Log In</div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  .right.item .ui.input {
    width:auto;
  }
```

Make the search bar container auto width so it gets smaller to fit the items on same row, and move the buttons container div to where you want it left or right(above or below respectively) the search container div.
The whole nav isn't responsive, so that's something i'd suggest. Unless that's intentional.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .right.item .ui.input {
    width:auto;
  }
</style>
<div class="ui menu">
        <a class="item" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="item" href="#">About</a>
        <a class="item" href="#">Contact us</a>
        <div class="right item" href="#">
            <div class="ui primary button">Sign Up</div>
            <div class="ui button">Log In</div>
            <div class="ui icon input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                <i class="search icon"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```